# Trying to get date from Calendar... app crashes

Tags: java, android, string, date, settext

**What I want?**: Write a method to:

- **1st**: Get date.
- **2nd**: Make it a String.
- **3rd**: setText(String) into an EditText.

**What I've done**:

```
private void setToday() {
    String dateToday = "";
    DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy, HH:mm");
    dateToday = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
    EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Title);
    dateToday = df.toString();
    title.setText(dateToday);
}
```

**Also**:

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
```

**EditText & Button**:

```
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Title" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Today"
            android:onClick="setToday"/>
```

**What should it do?**: In Utopia, this should get date, focus on EditText and put date into EditText.

**What it does?**: Button clicked = App crashes.

This is a brand new app. I've tryed even only:

```
private void setToday() {
        EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Title);
        title.setText("HOY");
    }
```

It still crashes. I'm doing something wrong, but cannot figure what it is.

EDIT: I managed to find logcat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find method setToday(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton

at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.resolveMethod(AppCompatViewInflater.java:327)

at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:284)

at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4232)

at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17298)

at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)

at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks for help.

PS: Here is all my code:

Java

```
package com.example.android.notastxt;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.EditText;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    private void setToday() {
        String dateToday = "HOY";
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy, HH:mm");
        dateToday = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Title);
        dateToday = df.toString();
        title.setText(dateToday);
    }

}
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.example.android.notastxt.MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/Title"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="Title" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Today"
            android:onClick="setToday"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:hint="Write" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Save" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What error do you get if connect your phone to the pc and watch logcat?

Comment: Let's start with catching an execption inside your method...

Comment: Ok. After breaking my head, I could finaly find logcat. I'm editing main post.

Comment: To let everyone know your problem is solved, please accept an answer by clicking the tick mark to the left of the answer. You may accept your own answer if you think it best describes the solution.

Comment: Thanks, Ole V.V. I'll do as soon as system allow me. Right now it promts: "You can accept your own answer in 11 hours".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deserve all your laughts. This was simply newbie mistake.

Changed

```
private void setToday() {
```

For

```
public void setToday(View View) {
```

*Voilà!* It worked flawlessly.

I used code from @Basil Bourque from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46415908/8662218

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy, HH:mm");
String dateToday = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Title);
title.setText(dateToday);
```

Thank you, Basil.

Problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Speaking just to your date-time work…

## Description of formatter?!

Your code:

```
String dateToday = "";
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy, HH:mm");
dateToday = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());  // <-- Good, you have your string representing date-time value. But then you replace it two lines below.
EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Title);
dateToday = df.toString();  // <-- Why ask for a description of the formatter?
title.setText(dateToday);
```

…is replacing your intended date-time string with a description of the formatter. Should be:

```
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MM yyyy, HH:mm");
String dateToday = df.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.Title);
title.setText(dateToday);
```

## Using java.time

Even better, stop using these troublesome old date-time classes. They are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. For Android, see the last bullets below.

`Instant` is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). It replaces `java.util.Date`, but with a finer resolution of nanoseconds rather than milliseconds.

```
Instant instant = Instant.now() ;
```

Apply the time zone through which you want to view the wall-clock time. For any given moment both the date and the time-of-day varies by zone. Noon in `Europe/Paris` is a much later time-of-day in `Asia/Kolkata` and a much earlier time-of-day in `America/Montreal`.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

Let java.time automatically localize.

```
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDateTime( FormatStyle.LONG ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

Or specify a custom pattern.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd MM uuuu, HH:mm" , locale ) ;
String output = zdt.format( f ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: The part about using ThreeTenABP and `java.time` is certainly good advice no matter what. It seems to me you are not explaining the reason for the crash that the asker experienced (I haven’t guessed the reason either).

Comment: @OleV.V. No, I don’t know why the crash, thus the first line line of my Answer.

Comment: I added logcat text to question.